# Confusion of parameter passing with rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I am a little confused of rvalue passing with a function call, see my code below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void func(std::string & s, char a) {
  std::cout << "here1" << std::endl;
  // ...
}

void func(std::string && s, char a) {
  std::cout << "here2" << std::endl;
  // ...
}

void foo(std::string && s) {
  func(s, ':');
}

int main(int agrc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string s = "a:b:c:d";
  func(std::move(s), ':'); // print here2
  char s2[8] = "a:b:c:d";
  func(std::move(std::string(s2)), ':'); // print here2
  foo(std::move(s2)); // print here1, why?
  return 0; 
}

g++-4.7 demo.cpp -std=c++11
```

Why the last case(using `foo`) prints `here1`?

In my view, inside function `foo`, `s` is an rvalue, so it will print `here2`.

Update:

`s` in `foo` is an lvalue, but there is no need to write a overload version of `foo`:

```
void foo(std::string & s) {
  func(s, ':');
}
```

Because compiler can learn whether the input parameter `s` is an rvalue or an lvalue, but why compiler do not auto move `s` in rvalue case?

Comment: It won't be auto moved for the same reason, it is an lvalue. lvalues are auto moved only in very limited contexts, such as a return statement from a function, where you're assured that its lifetime is coming to an end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration of `foo` :

```
void foo(std::string && s) {
  func(s, ':');
}
```

means that it can accept an rvalue reference, and this information is used for method resolution. However, within `foo` the parameter has a name, and is therefore as an lvalue reference. Basically it has decayed to a lvalue reference.

If you want to treat it as an rvalue reference when calling `func` then you need to covert it back to an rvalue refence by turning it back into an unnamed instance. This is what `std::move` accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

`s` is `lvalue` in function `foo`, not rvalue, because it's local function parameter, in which your `s2` will be moved. Since `rvalues` have no names and your variable has name - it's lvalue.  For correctly send it to `func` you can use `std::forward`, or `std::move`.

```
func(std::forward<std::string>(s), ':');
```

or

```
func(std::move(s), ':');
```

Comment: @xunzhang The variable `s` is of rvalue reference type, but the expression `s` is an lvalue. Anything named is an lvalue.

Comment: @xunzhang Another way to look at it is, within the body of `foo()` you can take the address of `s`, which means it is an lvalue. Add `std::cout << &s << std::endl;` to the body of that function and the code will still compile.

Answer (score 0):

Though the argument is passed as rvalue to `foo`, inside the function `foo`, it is seen as lvalue as it has got a name `s` and can be referenced by that name. Use `std::move` if you want to send rvalue using a "variable-name" (in simple terms, lvalue)

Below lecture by Scott Meyers explains move semantics in-detail. I recommend it if you want to know, and exploit move semantics

http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/move-semanticsperfect-forwarding-and-rvalue-references